Calculate double integral of a function $f(x,y)=(x-2)^2(\sqrt{1-y^4})$
I wanted to calculate the double integral over the area $D$, which is given by triangle $A\left(2,-1\right),\ B\left(2,0\right),\ C\left(4,-1\right)$, but I have issues because the fucntion is
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(x,y\right) =
\left(x - 2\right)^{2}\,\sqrt{\,{1 - y^{4}}\,}
$$

I tried my best using different techniques such as putting $y^{2} = \sin\left(u\right)$ and also calculating it by parts but none of them seem to work.
I wonder if, I'm missing some tricks that could work for my situation.
Here is the integral
$$
\int_{2}^{4}\int_{-1}^{-1/\left(2x\right) + 1}
\left(x - 2\right)^{2}\,\sqrt{\,{1 - y^{4}}\,}
\,\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x
$$


Lower bound for y should be $-1$, not $0$.

It is easier if you reverse the integration order:
$$
\int_{-1}^0\int_2^{2-2y}(x-2)^2 \sqrt{1-y^4} dy\, dx = \int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{1-y^4}\left[\frac{(x-2)^3}{3}\right]_{x=2}^{x=2-2y}dy = \frac 23\int_{-1}^0(-4y^3)\sqrt{1-y^4} dy = \cdots = \frac 49
$$

You can get numerical answer by Riemann integral. Each (x,y) point has "height" of f(x,y) and the integral just asks for the area under the height in a shape [2..4][0..-1/2x+1]. Riemann integral divides the area to pieces, samples each piece and gathers the results to a single number representing volume under the height.
